# Counting Account Level per Unique Customer

Tags: excel

I am working on a project and I need to count unique accounts per account level. I have the account number on column A and account level in column B. I have 3 account level, New, Standard and VIP.

On my current data If I use countif for New on column B I'm getting 5 but I remove the duplicate accounts there are only 3 unique accounts with account level "New."

I need a formula where it will count the Account level per unique accounts without removing the duplicates.

Comment: Could you please add an example of your excel data.

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper column with the formula

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A2=A2)*($B$2:$B2=B2))>1,0,1)
```

then use Sumif() based on that column or a pivot table to count where column C equals 1

[image]